# putchar_unlocked doesn't work in C++ 14 standard

Tags: c++, cygwin, posix

I am using g++ (GCC) 4.9.3 on Cygwin. I am not able to use `getchar_unlocked` or `putchar_unlocked` with C++ 14 standard.
Consider this sample code

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    putchar_unlocked('1');
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run with

```
g++ foo.cpp && a.exe && rm ./a.exe
```

I am getting expected output 1.
But when I do

```
g++ -std=c++14 foo.cpp && a.exe && rm ./a.exe
```

I am getting error saying putchar_unlocked was not declared.

```
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:4:22: error: 'putchar_unlocked' was not declared in this scope
  putchar_unlocked('1');
                      ^
```

Comment: ...Yeah. When you use `-std=*` options that force the compiler to conform to the standard, you don't get the non-standard functions. That's kind of the point, I'm not sure what you were expecting.

Comment: @hvd, working in [Ideone](https://ideone.com/wO7TPz)?

Comment: I see at least three possibilities for that: 1) Ideone isn't using `-std=c++14`. 2) Ideone is including additional command-line options to make non-standard functions available. 3) Ideone is using a non-conforming standard library implementation. The first two of these could be checked if Ideone documents which command-line options it passes to the compiler.

Comment: @hvd `putchar_unlocked` is perfectly standard POSIX.1-2001. I'm not certain if `#include <cstdio>` should provide it though, of if `#include <stdio.h>` should be used instead...

Comment: @hyde I should've specified "C standard". Yes, it is, but even then, only with either additional command-line options, or in non-conforming modes. Anyway, Cygwin doesn't conform to POSIX, although it does make many POSIX functions available in some form.

Comment: I don't see how this question is so downvoted. valid to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`putchar_unlocked` isn't part of any version of the C or C++ standards, and Cygwin doesn't implement any other standard that does provide `putchar_unlocked`.

Cygwin does provide `putchar_unlocked` as a non-standard extension, but you need to actually leave non-standard extensions enabled.

The default `-std=` version is `-std=gnu++03` (or one of its synonyms). This is C++03 plus extensions. You changed it to `-std=c++14`. This is C++14 *without* extensions. Use `-std=gnu++14` to leave extensions enabled.

Comment: Well, almost nothing implements any version of any standard exactly, but some approximations are good enough to be useful.

Comment: @n.m. Sure. I have no problem saying glibc closely conforms to POSIX, for instance, even if it has bugs, but Cygwin isn't in the same category. Cygwin doesn't aim to conform to POSIX, and actually lacks the part that's directly relevant to this question (the POSIX feature macros). Note that I certainly wouldn't say that makes Cygwin useless in general -- I use it extensively -- just not useful as an attempted POSIX implementation.

Answer (score 2):

`putchar_unlocked` is not part of any C++ standard. It is part of POSIX standard, but defining `-std=c++14` causes *gcc* to define `__STRICT_ANSI__` macro. *Cygwin* [uses](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.programming.glibc) [Newlib](https://sourceware.org/newlib/) for C standard library, and [from its sources](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=blob;f=newlib/libc/include/stdio.h;h=9d8fd862ef7363e12800f77ff78a485cf070bc49;hb=HEAD#l314) we can see that this prevents `putchar_unlocked` from being declared, and also that there isn't any other macro to enable it anyway.

Therefore, we need to get rid of `__STRICT_ANSI__`. Using `-std=gnu++14` should do that:

```
g++ -std=gnu++14 foo.cpp && a.exe && rm ./a.exe
```

---

A comment under the question points out that the code works with [Ideone](https://ideone.com/wO7TPz). This is probably, because Ideone runs on different platform (such as Linux), which probably has `glibc`, which provides `putchar_unlocked` with different conditions (from [this manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar_unlocked)):

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see
>   [feature_test_macros(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/feature_test_macros)):
>
> getc_unlocked(), getchar_unlocked(), putc_unlocked(),
>   putchar_unlocked():
>       _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 1 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE || _BSD_SOURCE || _SVID_SOURCE

Comment: That's the glibc documentation. The OP isn't using glibc.

Comment: Cygwin doesn't use glibc, and actually testing it, `_POSIX_SOURCE` doesn't make `putchar_unlocked` available.

Comment: @hvd obviously it's in *something* since the code seems to work with g++ default switches

Comment: @M.M Yes. It's available on Cygwin when no standards-conforming mode is used. Really. It's conditional in the Cygwin headers on `__STRICT_ANSI__` not being defined. So don't select a standards-conforming mode.

Comment: @krikx Edited, check the answer now!

Comment: @hvd Investigated, edited answer, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I think I already covered what you put in your edit in my previous comment and my answer, but there's no harm in having two answers cover it. :)

Comment: @hvd Yeah, I noticed your answer only after completing the rewrite, and since the answers don't overlap 100%, keeping both is probably good.